# Filtering for return value of a Method in PHP Lighthouse GraphQL

Tags: eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have a GraphQL query `findRecipe`, which returns an array of Eloquent models `recipe`, which is also defined in the schema. `recipe` has a field called `is_special_recipe` which is not a column  in the database, but a value calculated by a method. How can I filter for `is_special_recipe` in my `findRecipe` query?

```
    searchRecipe(
        name: String @where(operator: "LIKE")
        cooking_time_min: Int @where(operator: ">=")
        cooking_time_max: Int @where(operator: "<=")
        is_special_recipe: Boolean @where(operator: "eq")
    ): [Recipe] @paginate
```

```
type Recipe {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    image: String
    description: String
    cooking_time_min: Int
    cooking_time_max: Int
    is_special_recipe: Boolean @method(name: "isSpecialRecipe")
}
```

```
    public function isSpecialRecipe()
    {
        //some logic
        return false || true;
    }
```